# Split Compare Differences Window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, diff

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on a Windows 8 platform. Before I commit code, I open *Team Explorer* > *Pending Changes* and then *Compare with Latest Version* each file. I use the Diff window to cleanup my own code and for code review with a colleague. It's really a wonderful feature.

I have multiple monitors and can't figure out how to split the Diff window. I can float the window and stretch it, but it gets clunky when I want to minimize only one half and I can't see some text near the margin between monitors. 
Google helped me find a tool called WinMerge that allows for *different* (I won't say better) floating of the diff windows, but it's still contained in one clunky box that cannot be split.

Is there a way to "split float" the left and right halves of my diff Window to two different monitors but keep them line-number aligned?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that Visual Studio does not have the functionality to allow two windows to scroll simultaneously.  Your best course of action may be to try using a different text editor such as [Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously) to compare your code.